# Can't get mysqli_result::$fetch_all working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, debian, mysqlnd

I'm trying to get the fetch_all function working with mysqli. I know I need PHP > 5.3 and mysqlnd.

My server runs Debian Wheezy so I have PHP 5.5. I just removed php5-mysql and installed php5-mysqlnd.

`phpinfo()` shows that mysqlnd is installed, but when I try to use the fetch_all function I still get this error:

```
Undefined property: mysqli_result::$fetch_all
```

I call it like this:

```
$result->fetch_all[MYSQLI_ASSOC]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Call it like `$result->fetch_all()`, not `$result->$fetch_all`

Comment: Can you include your function usage? [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23786770/edit) to include the relevant code.

Comment: It'd be better if you posted the line of code that generated this error as well as the message.

Comment: @Maerlyn I'm calling it exactly like that.

Comment: @Compizfox use simple brackets `()` instead of square brackets `[]` for function calls.

Comment: Use `$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow, that was dumb. I completely overlooked that and I honestly thought it was a problem with my mysqlnd setup. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: It's ok. You can accept Marc B's answer below to close the question. Same difference ;-) Plus Maerlyn also made a note of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$result->fetch_all[MYSQLI_ASSOC]
```

is an array reference. `fetch_all` is a **METHOD**.

it should be

```
$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

note the change in bracket types.